# PS is not creating a new file everytime

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

I am using the following PS cmdlets to create a new json file every time it is executed. The existing json file should be overwritten

```
$jsonformatOutput = "JSON-BEGIN" + $jsonOutput + "JSON-END"
$jsonformatOutput | New-Item -path $myFileName -Force
```

However, a new json file is not created if their is already an existing one with the same filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`New-Item` isn't the function to choose for this situation (since it literally should only be used to create **New**-Items).

What you should use instead, is `Out-File`

```
$jsonformatOutput = "JSON-BEGIN" + $jsonOutput + "JSON-END"
$jsonformatOutput | Out-File -Filepath $myFileName
```

This writes the Variable to the file `$myFileName` and overwrites the file if it still exists.

If you want to add content to an existing file instead of overwriting it, you can use `-Append`.